# Laravel paginate chat not working

Tags: php, laravel, chat

I have code:

```
$conversations = Chat::conversations()->for($user)->limit(1)->page(1)->get();
```

This return `LengthAwarePaginator`. But currentPage from get request not change.

Working only:

```
$conversations = Chat::conversations()->for($user)->limit(1)->page($request->get('page'))->get();
```

Why?

I use package: https://github.com/musonza/chat

Comment: use `$conversations = Chat::conversations()->for($user)->limit(1)->paginate();` and laravel will do the other staffs for you

Comment: Not working method paginate

Comment: try `$conversations = Chat::conversations()->for($user)->limit(1)->paginate(10);`

Comment: Not working this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code always returns the first page because you've hardcoded it:

```
->page(1)
```

Laravel's pagination feature uses `$request->page` internally, so you don't need to specify the current page manually. But in this package you need to do that, so just use this code:

```
Chat::conversations()->for($user)->limit(1)->page($request->page)->get();
```

Comment: But I need validate `$request->get('page')`?

Comment: @Jadasdas no you don't need to validate it.

Comment: No you don't have to specify the page, the Collection object will hold information regarding the pages so whatever object is passed to the front-end will already know what page it is and what pages are before and after it.  All you have to do is call the `->paginate()` method and specify the number of records per page.